# Selecting an item in html selection menu

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following HTML and I am trying to go through it with selenuim to first select the select element and then choose a specific option by name/text

```
<div class="form-group" xpath="1">
<label for="team"><strong>Choose your option</strong></label>
<select name="team_id" class="form-control" style="">
<option value="8541">option1</option>
<option value="11377" style="">option2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I am currently trying the following
after opening the page, it first of all hard to identify if it is failing at selecting the variable 'select' or later in the loop through the option. However I think that with all I tried, it is not able to select the select many

```
optionvar= 'option2'
def registered():
    try:
        while True:
            try:
        driver.get(tournament+'/register')
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control'))
        print(select)
        for option in select.find_elements_by_tag_name('Option'):
            if option.text == optionvar:
                option.click()
                break
        except Exception as e:
            if 'NoSuchElementException' in str(e):
                print('Check In not Aktive jet')
                # Do the following
                # if you don't want to stop for loop then just continue
                continue

     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         pass
```

Now I tried a bunsh of stuff, element by name, or even xpath but somehow I am not able to select it and then choose the correct option

Please give me help on how to do this and how to better debug what is actually hapening in when its running.

Comment: Is the tag name case-sensitive? You may need 'option' instead of 'Option'. When using XPath, you may need to do "*:elementname" or specify the namespace appropriately.

Comment: It appears to be not case sensitive. My xpath try looked like this select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='team_id']")) do you mean it like this with "*:elementname"?

Answer (score 0):

The apparent answer was, just some syntax errors in the xpath

```
        select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='team_id']")
        for option in select.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
            if option.text in team:
                option.click() 
                break
```